# Unable to get content though NgForm

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I am using NgForm to get the form data.But the following error is displayed and nothing is rendered.

```
  Error: Template parse errors:
    There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "NgForm" ("<div class="add-issue">
        <h1>Add an issue</h1>
        <form [ERROR ->]#issueForm="NgForm" (ngSubmit)="addIssue(issueForm)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <l"): ng:///AppModule/CreateissueComponent.html@2:10
```

issue.component.html:

```
<div class="add-issue">
    <h1>Add an issue</h1>
    <form #issueForm="NgForm" (ngSubmit)="addIssue(issueForm)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Issue description:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="description" ngModel #inputSearch="ngModel"></textarea>
          </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sev">Severity</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="sev" name="sev" ngModel #inputSearch="ngModel">
            <option>Low</option>
            <option>Medium</option>
            <option>High</option>
          </select>
        </div> 

        <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

issue.component.ts:

```
addIssue(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);

  }
```

I have imported FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule,CommonModule in app.module.ts file and spec file.But still the issue persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngForm` is the directive that is exposed. Not `NgForm`

Change

```
<form #issueForm="NgForm" (ngSubmit)="addIssue(issueForm)">
```

to

```
<form #issueForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addIssue(issueForm)">
```

Comment: Thank u that helped

Comment: Glad it did. Happy Jamming :)